# How do I create a IS NOT NULL where clause in Yii ActiveRecord?

Tags: php, activerecord, yii2

I tried the following

```
$kw = Keyword::find()->leftJoin('ad_group_keyword', 'keyword_id = keyword.id')->where(['keyword_id' => null, ['not', ['revenue' => null]]])->all();
```

But it gave me an error

> PHP Warning – yii\base\ErrorException
>   strtoupper() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

[screenshot http://ipfs.pics/ipfs/QmcoACjLBmTYL3GZd6qG5GoRopVntCohurqWz3BXhbLzTZ](http://ipfs.pics/ipfs/QmcoACjLBmTYL3GZd6qG5GoRopVntCohurqWz3BXhbLzTZ)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it with `andWhere`:

```
$kw = Keyword::find()
             ->leftJoin('ad_group_keyword', 'keyword_id = keyword.id')
             ->where(['keyword_id' => null])
             ->andWhere(['not', ['revenue' => null]])
             ->all();
```